# Solution to a higher order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $q$ be a strictly positive integer and let $\beta \neq q$ be a real number. Consider a following Ordinary Differential Equation(ODE):
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^q r_t}{d t^q} + \frac{1}{t^\beta} r_t = 0
\end{equation}
Using Mathematica I have checked that the fundamental solutions to that ODE reads:
\begin{equation}
r_t^{(\eta)} = t^\eta F_{0,q-1}\left[\begin{array}{c} \{\} \\ \left\{ 1+ \frac{\xi}{q-\beta} \right\}_{\xi=1}^\eta  \cup  \left\{ 1- \frac{\xi}{q-\beta} \right\}_{\xi=1}^{q-1-\eta} \end{array}; -\frac{t^{q-\beta}}{(q-\beta)^q}\right]
\end{equation}
where $\eta=0,\cdots,q-1$. Here $F_{p,q}$ is the hypergeometric function. The quantity on the bottom of the square brackets is understood as a concatenation of two sequences the first one of length $\eta$ and the second one of length $q-1-\eta$.
In the special case $q=2$ the fundamental solutions read:
\begin{equation}
\left(
\sqrt{t} J_{\frac{1}{-2+\beta}}\left[\frac{t^{1-\frac{\beta}{2}}}{\frac{\beta}{2}-1}\right]
,
\sqrt{t} J_{\frac{-1}{-2+\beta}}\left[\frac{t^{1-\frac{\beta}{2}}}{\frac{\beta}{2}-1}\right]
\right)
\end{equation}
where $J_\beta$ is the Bessel function. The solutions match those given in [Solution to a second order ordinary differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673737/solution-to-a-second-order-ordinary-differential-equation) .

Is there a way to derive the solutions using some different method?

Answer (score 0):

Note, that integrating our ODE $q$ times and  solving the resulting integral equation by successive iterations we end up with the following solution in terms of infinite series:
\begin{equation}
r_t = \sum\limits_{\eta=0}^{q-1} r^{(\eta)}_0 \sum\limits_{p=0}^\infty \frac{1}{((q-1)!)^p} I^{(t,t_ 0)}_{\vec{q}_\eta,p}
\end{equation}
where $\vec{q}_\eta := (q-1,q-1,\cdots,q-1,\eta)$ where the number $q-1$ is repeated $p$ times. The initial conditions of the ODE are 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^\eta  r_t }{ d t^\eta}(t= t_0) = r^{(\eta)}_0
\end{equation}
for $\eta=0,\cdots,q-1$ and the quantities $I^{(t,t_ 0)}_{\vec{q}_\eta,p}$ are multivariable integrals over a simplex, defined in [Yet another multivariable integral over a simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995158/yet-another-multivariable-integral-over-a-simplex) . 
For simplicity we only consider the last ($\eta=q-1$ ) term only. Using the closed form solution for the multivariable integral we easily arrive at the following special solution:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{l=0}^{q-1} \binom{q-1}{l} (-1)^l \\&& 
F_{0,q-1}\left[\begin{array}{c} \left\{\right\} \\ \left\{ 1 - \frac{l-\eta}{q-\beta}\right\}_{\stackrel{\eta=0}{\eta\neq l}}^{q-1}\end{array}; - \frac{t^{q-\beta}}{(q-\beta)^q}\right]
F_{0,q-1}\left[\begin{array}{c} \left\{\right\} \\ \left\{ 1 + \frac{l+\eta}{q-\beta}\right\}_{\stackrel{\eta=0}{\eta\neq l}}^{q-1}\end{array}; (-1)^q \frac{t_0^{q-\beta}}{(q-\beta)^q}\right] t^{q-1-l} t_0^l
\end{eqnarray}
We will further simplify the result soon.